# Oracle Weblogic 11g CharBuffer cannot be resolved, JDK 1.8

Tags: java, weblogic

have Oracle Weblogic 11g installed and have some problems when using Apache IOUtils in my JSP page.

I get this kind of error:

```
Root cause of ServletException. weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: 
Failed to compile JSP /getfile.jsp getfile.jsp:234:35: 
The type java.nio.CharBuffer cannot be resolved. 
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files while 
((lengthc = rdr.read(bufc)) != -1) { ^-----------^ 
getfile.jsp:236:25: The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It 
is indirectly referenced from required .class files bu.append(bufc[x]);
```

The source code of my JSP page is:

```
InputStream podatki = blob.getBinaryStream();
OutputStream strBlob = new FileOutputStream(blobFile);
try {
      IOUtils.copy(podatki, strBlob);
} finally {
IOUtils.closeQuietly(podatki);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(strBlob);
}
```

The server is using java.version = 1.8.0_151

Have tried also to rebuild the project with JDK 1.8 but I get always the same error while on some other Weblogic server with JDK 1.7 installed all works well.

Maybe the solution would be to downgrade JDK on the server side?

Comment: `CharBuffer` and `CharSequence` were introduced in `1.4`. Your things are borked.

Comment: What does this mean? I have included Apache commons-io-2.6.jar and commons-cli-1.4.jar into project.

Comment: Who cares about commons? They're `java.lang` classes and have been around since `1.4` and they haven't been **removed**. If you're getting those kinds of errors it means there's something seriously wrong with your server configurations.

Comment: Ok ok.. understand.. the compiler can't find CharBuffer and CharSequence which were introduced in Jdk 1.4 and newer.

Comment: Here is the same problem...  https://www.codesd.com/item/the-java-nio-charbuffer-type-can-not-be-resolved.html